# Display 1 column values to 3 different columns in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Hey guys i am usnig sql 11g. i came across one situation where my table have 1 column like this

```
column1
1
john
2000
2
david
4000
4
eon
5000
```

and i want output to split into 3 different columns like

```
id     name     salary
1      john      2000
2      david     3000
4      eon       5000
```

Comment: I suspect it is about Oracle 11G

Comment: its 11g only...

Comment: Hi @Avinash, the full table definition script would be nice to have. The thing is database dies not guarantee the order of lines to be returned unless "order by" is being used. So we need at least to see a column to order the data or perhaps we may find out the easier way to help you out

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your transformation seems to require an ordering of the rows -- but that information needs to be in a column, which is not in the data.  You cannot do what you want with the data you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

With just that 1 column in a table you will have dreadful trouble getting the desired output. In SQL tables are "unordered sets" so there is no guarantee that the data will be extracted in the exact same order you display it above - but to achieve the desired output we must have a reliable order of rows.

Assuming there is no other column in that table I would suggest you need to add an ID column like this:

```
alter table mytable
add (
    id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
    )

+---------+----+
| COLUMN1 | ID |
+---------+----+
| 1       |  1 |
| john    |  2 |
| 2000    |  3 |
| 2       |  4 |
| david   |  5 |
| 4000    |  6 |
| 4       |  7 |
| eon     |  8 |
| 5000    |  9 |
+---------+----+
```

which (hopefully) will add the information we can then use to help order the output:

In the following we use lag by 1 row, and lead by 1 row to widen the data into 3 column, and then also use modulus of 3 on the id column to select just the wanted rows that have values in all 3 columns:

```
select id, name, salary
from (
    select 
      mod(id,3) AS mod3
    , lag(column1, 1) over(order by id)  as id
    , column1                            as name
    , lead(column1, 1) over(order by id) as salary
    from mytable
)
where mod3 = 2

+----+-------+--------+
| ID | NAME  | SALARY |
+----+-------+--------+
|  1 | john  |   2000 |
|  2 | david |   4000 |
|  4 | eon   |   5000 |
+----+-------+--------+
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/markdown?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d6ce4015c83254ca2a6d8e49a4db5781)

Answer (score 0):

Schema:

```
 create table table1 (column1 varchar(50));

 insert into table1
 with cte as (select '1'from dual
 union all
 select 'john' from dual
 union all
 select '2000'from dual
 union all
 select '2'from dual
 union all
 select 'david'from dual
 union all
 select '4000'from dual
 union all
 select '4'from dual
 union all
 select 'eon'from dual
 union all
 select '5000'from dual
 )
  select * from cte
```

Query:

```
 with cte as 
 (
     select column1,( ( Row_number()OVER(ORDER BY 1 ) - 1 ) / 3 ) + 1 rn from table1
 )
 , cte2 as
 (
     select column1,rn, row_number()over(partition by NVL(SUBSTR(rn, 0, INSTR(rn, '.')-1), rn) order by rn) rnk  ,NVL(SUBSTR(rn, 0, INSTR(rn, '.')-1), rn)grp
     from cte 
 )
 select max("1")ID,max("2")Name,max("3")Salary from(
 select *  from cte2)
 pivot (max(column1) for rnk in (1,2,3))
 group by grp
 order by grp
```

Output:

| ID | NAME | SALARY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | john | 2000 |
| 2 | david | 4000 |
| 4 | eon | 5000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9a687072e766832f4caeaea443d8ac27)*

Comment: `order by 1` does not mimic the wanted order, sadly the results are not reliable, try it

Comment: Yes I know that the order is not guaranteed. But does adding identity column at later point always guarantee the order?

Comment: Adding the identity won't guarantee the correct order initially, but it will establish a consistent basis for ordering.

Comment: @Avihash hope your problem has been resolved.